# Deploy kube-prometheus-stack with Kustomize don't work

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, kustomize

I am trying to deploy kube-prometheus-stack
https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack through kustomize. But I am getting from the deployment:

```
unable to recognize ".": no matches for kind "Alertmanager" in version "monitoring.coreos.com/v1"
unable to recognize ".": no matches for kind "Prometheus" in version "monitoring.coreos.com/v1"
unable to recognize ".": no matches for kind "PrometheusRule" in version "monitoring.coreos.com/v1"
...(and so on)
```

Full output under: https://app.warp.dev/block/JJwOYMJZng9CyBdVlBaIIF

I tried to deploy local on rancher desktop but on docker desktop I get the same.

What I did:
There are nor kustomize file for this stack so I take the manifest with:

```
helm template prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack > prometheus.yaml
```

after this didn't work I tried to take directly in my kustomize.yaml the helm with:

```
 helmCharts:
 - name: kube-prometheus-stack 
   repo: https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
   version: 35.0.3
   releaseName: prometheus
```

and started kustomize with:

```
kubectl kustomize . --enable-helm | kubectl apply -f -
```

both have the same problem.

If use helm with:

```
helm install prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack
```

its working.

What interesting is that when I uninstall it:

```
helm uninstall prometheus
```

and then deploy it again through kustomize

```
kubectl apply -k .
```

Its working, but it is not the solution which I need. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give kubernetes some time to create CRDs before trying to deploy objects that "use" those CRDs.

Next time just do the apply one time, wait 10 seconds and do the apply again. even several times until the errors disappear.

Comment: Before helm install I tried with with helm install --dry-run.  Any idea why the error.

Comment: You are missing the CRDs... you need to install kind alertmanager, kind prometheus, etc..

Comment: Thank you, While applying the crd from specific CRD folder     https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/crds                                   
kubectl apply -f crd-prometheuses.yaml
**The CustomResourceDefinition "prometheuses.monitoring.coreos.com" is  invalid : metadata.annotations: Too long: must have at most 262144 bytes**

Comment: And as per https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack.                                           **$helm install [RELEASE_NAME] prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack** should work?

Comment: This worked  kubectl **create** -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/v0.57.0/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_prometheuses.yaml.

Comment: yes, kubectl create -f solves the "too long issue"

Comment: Thank you. Now I am facing this issue.  **listening failed:10250listen tcp :10250: bind: address already in use**                                                                      https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/issues/2248

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Helmfile. When the CRDs are deployed at the same time (in the same chart or even as Helmfile dependency) as the resources, Helmfile validation will fail :

```
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: [unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Alertmanager" in version "monitoring.coreos.com/v1", unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Prometheus" in version "monitoring.coreos.com/v1", unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "ServiceMonitor" in version "monitoring.coreos.com/v1"]
```

However, Kubernetes agent is perfectly capable of handling crd/resource creation at the same time. The solution with Helmfile was to disable validation on first deploy :

`helmfile.yaml`

```yaml
releases:
- name: prometheus
  disableValidation: true # Missing CRDs on first deploy
  installed: true
  values:
    - values.yaml
```

It's the only workaround I have found so far,
I'm not very familiar with Kustomize, but I suppose there must be a way to skip validation as well ?

Hope this helps anyway

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting `helmCharts.includeCRDs: true` in `kustomization.yaml`.

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: monitoring

helmCharts:
  - name: kube-prometheus-stack
    repo: https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
    version: 45.28.1
    includeCRDs: true
    releaseName: kube-prometheus-stack
    namespace: monitoring
    valuesFile: values.yaml
```

Comment: Great, i need to try it out